# Spring Kafka consumer much slower in consumption in batches compared to Spring cloud stream

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Spring Kafka (2.2.2.RELEASE), when retrieving records in batches we see a performance issue.

Using Spring cloud stream, we are able to consume around ~80k rpm, the same with Spring Kafka using batches (with batch size of either 50 or 500) we are able to consume ~8k rpm.

Are there any performance concerns with consumption in Spring Kafka with batches or we are missing any configuration which can fine tune this?

**Spring Kafka code:**
ConcurrentKafkaConsumerListener:

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ConcurrentKafkaConsumerListenerConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SomeResourceDeserialiser.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "batch");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "500");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);

    return factory;
  }
```

Consumer:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Profile(Profiles.SOME)
public class SomeKafkaConsumer {

  @Value("${li.enable-api}")
  private boolean shouldMakeAPICall;

  @KafkaListener(topics = "SomeTopic", id = "batch-listener-test-0001")
  public void receiveData(@Payload List<SomeResource> someResources,
      Acknowledgment acknowledgment,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
      @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) {
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
}
```

Deserialiser:

```
public class SomeResourceDeserialiser implements Deserializer<SomeResource> {

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
  }

  @Override
  public SomeResource deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
    if (data != null) {
      try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
      objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
      objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        return objectMapper.readValue(data, SomeResource.class);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {

  }
}
```

**Spring cloud stream code:**

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          some-consumer-channel:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
        binder:
          brokers: broker:9092,localhost:29092
          autoCreateTopics: false
          autoAddPartitions: false
      bindings:
        some-consumer-channel:
          destination: topics
```

Consumer:

```
@EnableBinding(SomeStream.class)
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
@Profile(Profiles.Some)
public class SomeKafkaConsumer {

  @StreamListener(SomeStream.SOME_CONSUMER_CHANNEL)
  public void receiveData(Message<SomeResource> someResource) {
}
}
```

SomeStream:

```
public interface SomeStream {

  @java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S1214")
  String SOME_CONSUMER_CHANNEL = "some-consumer-channel";

  @Input(SOME_CONSUMER_CHANNEL)
  SubscribableChannel someConsumerChannel();
}
```

SomeResource:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Slf4j
public class SomeResource {

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String someId;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String someotherId;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String state;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String someanotherId;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String market;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private int quantity;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private ZonedDateTime lastUpdatedTimestamp;

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  private String traceId;

  public SomeResource() {
    // Default constructor
  }
}
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream uses Spring Kafka underneath so something else is going on. You need to show code and configuration for both scanarios.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. Found the issue, our deserialiser in Spring Kafka was having performance issue because of creating the objectMapper instance each time. 
Thank you for the quick reply!!